# Android: Using attributes in selector

Tags: android, attributes, android-selector

I'm trying to create a selector that uses attributes defines by the selected theme.

attrs.xml

```
<declare-styleable name="ThemeColors">
    <attr name="buttonTextColor" format="color" />
</declare-styleable>
```

selector.xml

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item android:state_pressed="true" android:color="@android:color/black" />
    <item android:color="?attr/buttonTextColor"/>
</selector>
```

Theme:

```
<style name="Theme.Test" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat">
    <item name="buttonTextColor">@android:color/white</item>
</style>
```

Part of the layout file:

```
  <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/test"
        android:textColor="@drawable/selector" />
```

Manifest

```
<application
    ...
    android:theme="@style/Theme.Test" >
```

The layout file is inflated by the `setContentView` method.

Now the problem is that the textcolor is `RED` in the unpressed state (and black when pressed). It seems like it cannot find the `buttonTextColor` and uses the default `RED`(?)

Already tried to set the theme to the Application Context, but no luck..

Thanks in advance.